# Add HTML/JS/CSS GUI to OpenGL app (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, html, opengl-es

The OpenGL ES 3 application I'm developing has reached a point where I  need to construct the GUI using standard HTML/JS/CSS.

I've looked at Awesomium and Chromium for desktop and both are viable options. However, I've not come across a viable option for iOS and Android.

Is it possible to overlay a WebView/WKWebView on top of an OpenGL surface? Or perhaps place an OpenGL surface inside a WebView/WKWebView and render the HTML GUI around the OpenGL graphics?

Comment: @BDL Why did you remove the opengl tag? It's perfectly viable

Comment: I completely understand your concerns. The reason is that the answer to your question will be specific to OpenGL-ES and will not be usefull for desktop OpenGL (which is targeted by the opengl tag). Please have a look at the [tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/info) which states: "...OpenGL ES (OpenGL for Embedded Systems) has its own tag".